# Could not import identity in Xcode while migrating to new mac

Tags: ios, xcode

I followed the instructions on https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-accounts_preferences/articles/export_signing_assets.html to migrate my developer identity to a new computer on Xcode, but when I try to import it on the new mac, I get the following error:

> The user name or passphrase you entered is not correct..

What's this supposed to be? It's not the password, because if I type the wrong password, I get a different error message.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by restarting my macbook pro and import again.